# How to put differents picfures with *ng?

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-code, angular9

I'm a beginner in Angular and I'm trying to create an application that looks like CapitalistAdventure.. For my products, I'm using an *ngFor but I don't know how to give each of them a differents pictures, productName and productNumber. I did some research and tried some things but nothing works. Can someone explain me how to do it please ? 
My app looks like that:

[image]
[image]
Here is the code that I have for my app.component.html:

```
  <h1><span id="WorldName">{{world.name}}WORLDNAME</span></h1>
  <!--<span id="WorldImage"><img [attr.src]="server+world.logo"/></span>-->
  <div class="UserData">
    <div class="Money">
      <span id="MoneyName">Money:</span>
      <br>
      <!--<span [innerHTML]="world.money | bigvalue"></span>-->
      <span>$</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Buy">
      <span id="BuyName">Buy</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ID">
      <span id="MoneyName">ID :</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Game">
    <div class="UpgradeContainer">
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Unlock')">Unlocks</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Cash')">Cash</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Angels')">Angels</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Managers')">Managers</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Investors')">Investors</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductContainer">
      <app-product *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product"></app-product>
    </div>
</div>
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RestserviceService } from 'src/app/restservice.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { BigvaluePipe } from './bigvalue.pipe';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    BigvaluePipe,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
  ],
  providers: [RestserviceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.ts:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RestserviceService } from './restservice.service'; 
import { World, Product, Pallier } from './world';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularProject';
  world: World = new World(); 
  server: String;
  products = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  modal: String;

  constructor(private service: RestserviceService) { 
    this.server = service.getServer(); 
    service.getWorld().then(world => { this.world = world; });   
  }

  setModal(value: String){
    this.modal = value;
  }
}
```

My product.component.html:

```
<div class="Product">
  <div class="ProductInfo">
    <img onclick="alert('Production lancé'), starFabrication() " class="ProductImage" src="./assets/Avatar.jpg">
    <!--<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" class="ProgressBar" [value]="progressbarvalue"></mat-progress-bar>-->
    <div class="ProductNumber">ProductNumber</div>
    <div class="ProductPrice">ProductPrice</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally my product.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/world';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  product: Product;
  @Input()
  set prod(value: Product){
    this.product = value;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

The code for my app.component.css:

```
:host{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #282828;
}
h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 42px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(201, 157, 69), rgb(218, 174, 80));
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.UserData{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.ID{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #f7d493, goldenrod);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
  0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507);
}
.Buy{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #f7d493, goldenrod);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
  0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507);
}
.Money{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #f7d493, goldenrod);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
  0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507);
}
.Game{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.UpgradeContainer{
  width: 180px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.Upgrade{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #f5c977, #d3a23f);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
  0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507);
}
.ProductContainer{
  padding: 0.1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Finally my product.component.css:

```
:host {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #f7b733;
  color: white;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 2em - 5px);
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.747), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
  0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.767);
}
.ProductImage{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
}
.ProductProgressBar{
display: inline;
position: relative;
bottom: 40px;
left: 5px;
}
.ProductNumber{
margin: 0.5em;
padding: 0;
border: 2px solid grey;
border-radius: 7px;
color: goldenrod;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
.ProductPrice{
margin: 0.5em;
padding: 0;
border: 2px solid grey;
border-radius: 7px;
color: goldenrod;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
}
```

I thank in advance anybody who would be kind enough to help me :D.

Comment: Please try to minimize the code you have to what is relevant. No one is going to read through your entire application. There is a lot of irrelevant ccs here. Also please remove the ```visual-studio-code``` tag. It is not in the scope of the question. As for your issue please go through the example app on Angular's site (https://angular.io/start), just like it does, you would have a list of products in your component, one of the fields of the type ```product``` would be the img path and than you can use ngStyle inside the ngFor to set the background  https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 1):

The problem  there is that your product list is just an array of numbers. It should be an array of your products, so you can access it attributes inside the child component. Try something like this:

In your `app.component.ts` you should set products as the list of products you want, maybe like this:

```
products = [
{ productName: 'name one', productNumber: 21, image: 'url for image' },
{ productName: 'name two', productNumber: 13, image: 'url for image' },
{ productName: 'name three', productNumber: 4, image: 'url for image' }
]
```

in `product.component.html` , set this:

```
<div class="Product">
  <div class="ProductInfo">
    <img onclick="alert('Production lancé'), starFabrication() " 
      class="ProductImage" [src]="product.image">
    <div class="ProductNumber">{{product.productNumber}}</div>
    <div class="ProductPrice">{{product.productName}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi, Fist thanks a lot for the help :). It works but in the product.component.html I have an error for "product.image". It says "Identifier 'image' is not defined. 'Product' does not contain such a member". It is normal ? I was told to add an "?" but it does not work :/ .

Comment: No problem! First of all, make sure you are passing an valid image url to the component. How is your product list now?

Comment: They are listed with the differents name, picture and number.